# Was Muhsin Ibn Ali (Radhi'allahu'anhu) a grandson of our beloved Prophet Muhammad (SAW), according to authentic Sunni sources?

Tags: prophet-muhammad, sunni, shia-sunni, ahl-ul-bayt

I tried to search online but I was not able to find answers. I want to know if our beloved Prophet Muhammad (Sallallahu'alayhiwassalam) had a third grandson whose name was Muhsin Ibn Ali (Radhi'allahu'anhu), according to authentic Sunni sources. **Is Muhsin Ibn Ali (Radhi'allahu'anhu) considered a grandson of our beloved Prophet Muhammad (Sallallahu'alayhiwassalam) by Sunnis?**

Comment: Well the [Arabic wikipedia site on Fatimah](https://ar.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D9%81%D8%A7%D8%B7%D9%85%D8%A9_%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B2%D9%87%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%A1#%D8%A3%D8%A8%D9%86%D8%A7%D8%A4%D9%87%D8%A7) actually clearly confirms this for both shi'a and sunnis (المحسن بن علي) See also [Muhsin ibn 'Ali](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muhsin_ibn_Ali).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imam ad-Dhahbi quoted in his short biography of Fatimah bint Rassuli Allah () فاطمة بنت رسول الله  -in Siiyar a'laam an-Nubalaa' [سير أعلام النبلاء](https://islamweb.net/ar/library/index.php?page=bookcontents&idfrom=142&idto=142&bk_no=60&ID=118)  the following:
<sup>In the following I'm translating from Arabic language. As these translations are of my own take them with the necessary care</sup>.

> وقال ابن عبد البر : دخل بها بعد وقعة أحد . فولدت له الحسن ، والحسين ، ومحسنا ، وأم كلثوم ، وزينب .
> Ibn Abd al-Barr said: Her -with 'Ali- marriage was consumed after the incident of Uhud. She bore him Hassan, Hussein, Mohsen, Umm Kulthum, and Zainab.

Ibn Kathir quoted in his history al-Bidyah wa an-Nihayah (Volume 7) [البداية والنهاية](https://web.archive.org/web/20141226225344/http://ar.wikisource.org/wiki/%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A8%D8%AF%D8%A7%D9%8A%D8%A9_%D9%88%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%86%D9%87%D8%A7%D9%8A%D8%A9/%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AC%D8%B2%D8%A1_%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B3%D8%A7%D8%A8%D8%B9/%D8%B0%D9%83%D8%B1_%D8%B2%D9%88%D8%AC%D8%A7%D8%AA%D9%87_%D9%88%D8%A8%D9%86%D9%8A%D9%87_%D9%88%D8%A8%D9%86%D8%A7%D8%AA%D9%87) the following:

> قال الإمام أحمد: حدثنا حجاج، ثنا إسرائيل، عن أبي إسحاق، عن هانئ بن هانئ، عن علي قال: لما ولد الحسن جاء رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم فقال: « أروني ابني، ما سميتموه؟ »
> Imam Ahmad said: Hajjaj infomred us, Israel informed us, on the authority of Abu Ishaq, on the authority of Haani' Bin Haani', on the authority of 'Ali who said:
> When Al-Hassan was born, the Messenger of God, may God’s prayers and peace be upon him, came and said: «Show me my son, what you called him? »
> فقلت: سميته حربا.
> فقال: « بل هو حسن ».
> I said: I called it him Harb (war).
> He said: "Rather, he is Hassan (good)."
> فلما ولد الحسين قال: « أروني ابني، ما سميتموه؟ »
> فقلت: سميته حربا.
> قال: « بل هو حسين ».
> When Al-Hussein was born, he said: “Show me my son. What did you call him? »
> I said: I called him Harb (war).
> He said, "Rather, he is Hussein."
> لما ولد الثالث، جاء النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم فقال: « أروني ابني، ما سميتموه؟ »
> فقلت: حربا.
> فقال: « بل هو محسن، ثم قال: إني سميتهم اسم ولد هارون شبر وشبير ومشبر »
> When the third was born, the Prophet, may God bless him and grant him peace, came and said: «Show me my son, what did you name? »
> So I said: Harb (war).
> He said: "Rather, he is a Mohsin, then he said: I named them -like- the name of Aaron’s son, Shabar, Shabeer and Mushabir."

He further quoted that ibn Sa'ad mentioned the same narration with a different narrator chain starting with a statement of 'Ali (), but he didn't mention "When the third was born":

> قال علي: كنت رجلا أحب الحرب، فلما ولد الحسن هممت أن أسميه حربا، فذكر الحديث بنحو ما تقدم،
> Ali said: I was a man who loved war. When Al-Hassan was born, I wanted to call him war, and he mentioned the hadith in the aforementioned manner.

See also in As-Sunan al-Kubra of imam al-Bayhaqi Hadith [#12148 here](https://web.archive.org/web/20050401005317/http://www.islamweb.net/ver2/archive/showHadiths2.php?BkNo=21&KNo=32&BNo=2602) or [#11594 here](https://islamweb.net/ar/library/index.php?page=bookcontents&ID=11594&bk_no=71&flag=1), and in imam Ahmad's al-Musnad #[3706](https://sunnah.com/ahmad/5/378).

Ibn Kathir also add:

> فأول زوجة تزوجها علي رضي الله عنه فاطمة بنت رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم، بنى بها بعد وقعة بدر، فولدت له الحسن وحسينا ويقال: ومحسنا ومات وهو صغير.
> The first wife 'Ali, may Allah be pleased with him, married was Fatima, the daughter of the Messenger of Allah, may God bless him and grant him peace. He consummated it after the battle of Badr, and she bore him Hassan and Hussayn, and it is said: And Muhssin who died when he was young.
> وولدت له زينب الكبرى، وأم كلثوم، وهذه تزوج بها عمر بن الخطاب كما تقدم.
> And she bore him Zaynab al-Kubra and Umm Kulthum, and this was married to Umar ibn al-Khattab, as mentioned earlier.
> ولم يتزوج علي على فاطمة حتى توفيت بعد رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم بستة أشهر.
> Ali did not marry another wife (beside) Fatima until she died six months after the Messenger of Allah, may Allah bless him and grant him peace.

Some articles say that this son might have been a death birth.

Comment: Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 0):

The children whose mother is Hazrat Fatemeh (PBUH) (the daughter of the Messenger of God (PBUH)), including Imam Hassan (AS) and Imam Hussein (AS) and Mohsen and Zeinab Kobra and Umm Kulthum Kobra. Mohsen had an abortion during the attack on the house of Hazrat Zahra (PBUH). Ibn Athir says: Mohsen died as a child. Zainab married Abdullah ibn Ja'far ibn Abi Talib and Umm Kulthum became the wife of Umar ibn al-Khattab. But the views of the Sunnis are as follows Hazrat Zahra (PBUH) was the only survivor of the Messenger of God (PBUH) whose sweet life ended after her death. There was no sweet time in the life of that lady.

Because the pressures, wars and conspiracies of the enemies on the head of Islam and the Holy Prophet (PBUH) constantly disturbed the peace of the soul of Fatima (PBUH). But with the demise of the Holy Prophet (PBUH) new storms of complex and critical events began to blow, the grudges of Badr, Khyber and Hanin, which were hidden under the ashes in the time of the Holy Prophet (PBUH), became apparent. For this reason, he went to the grave of the Holy Prophet (PBUH) and felt sorry for him: Dear father! After you, I was alone and alone, I was amazed and lost, my voice turned to silence, and my back broke and the refreshing water of life became bitter in my mouth. And it was always the case that 75 days or 95 days had not passed since the death of the Holy Prophet (PBUH) who joined his noble father due to the sufferings he saw, and therefore it can be said that the martyrdom of that great lady is an undeniable truth and one of the certainties of Islamic history. So that no one can work, because Shiite and Sunni historians and narrators have described it in spite of various pressures and statements, and here are some of them. Of course, it should be acknowledged that the meaning of the martyrdom of Fatemeh Zahra (PBUH) is that she suffered after the death of the Holy Prophet (PBUH) in suffering, pain, oppression and cruelty by the enemies of the Ahl al-Bayt (AS). Eventually, it led to the martyrdom of that Imam.

Ibn Qutaybah Dinuri writes: The same day that Abu Bakr learned from some people who had disobeyed allegiance to him and had gathered with Ali (AS). So he sent Omar to those who had gathered in Ali's house. So they refused to leave the house, at which time Omar ordered you to bring firewood. Addressing the people of the house, he said: I swear to the one in whose hands Omar's life must be taken out, otherwise I will set the house on fire with his family. What Fatima is at home. In the same source, he mentions that after a few days, Abu Bakr told Umar to go to Fatemeh Zahra (PBUH) because we had made her angry. They went to Fatemeh Zahra (PBUH) together, but Fatimah allowed them to enter. He did not, but they entered the house through the mediation of Ali (AS), but Hazrat Fatemeh Zahra (AS) did not speak to them. Shahrestani quotes from another book of the system: On the day of the people's allegiance to Abu Bakr, who was in charge of this matter and Omar was ordered to take allegiance from Ali and those who were in his house! He shouted loudly to set fire to Ali's house and he himself hit Fatemeh Zahra (PBUH) on the abdomen so much that Fatemeh threw her fetus from her abdomen. Ibn Hajar also quotes Muhammad ibn Hammad Kufi in his book that he believes that Umar undoubtedly kicked the belly of Hazrat Fatemeh Zahra (PBUH) and this led to the abortion of Fatemeh Zahra (PBUH) whose name is Mohsen Ibn Ali Was led. It can be seen that although some Sunni scholars have refrained from recounting this true piece of history in order to preserve the position of the caliphs and have considered it as a Shiite belief and thought, nevertheless a large number of Sunni scholars have not been able to They cover up the reality, even though they did not narrate the whole incident and only mentioned it briefly.

In this regard, Seyyed Morteza quotes that at the beginning of the work, narrators and historians did not refrain from quoting the disrespect that entered the field of the daughter of the Holy Prophet of Islam (PBUH). It was well-known among them that the caliph's agent pressed the door on Fatemeh Zahra (PBUH) and she aborted the child she was in the womb, and Qanfaz, under the command of Umar, whipped Fatemeh Zahra (PBUH) so that she He took it from Ali, but later they saw that the narration of these matters was not compatible with the position of the caliphs, so they refused to narrate them. Muqatil Ibn Atiyah says: Abu Bakr, after taking allegiance from the people with threats, fear and swords, sent Umar, Qanfiz and a group to the door of Fatima and Ali. Set on fire. When Fatemeh Zahra (PBUH) came from behind, Omar and her companions gathered and Omar pushed Hazrat Fatemeh Zahra (PBUH) behind the door so much that she aborted her child and a nail went into the chest of Hazrat (PBUH) (and as a result of those injuries He became ill and fell into bed until he died.

Another Sunni scholar, who is a Shafi'i, quotes a person named Ibn Dram al-Muhaddith as saying that Omar definitely kicked Fatemeh Zahra (peace be upon her) and had an abortion as a result of Mohsen's blow to her abdomen. This is a beautiful example given by this Sunni scholar ::: Ibn Abi al-Hadid al-Mu'tazili narrates: Abu al-'As, the husband of Zainab, the daughter of the Holy Prophet (PBUH), was taken prisoner by the Muslims during the war, but was later released like other captives. Abu al-'As promised the Holy Prophet (PBUH) that after returning to Mecca, he would send Zainab to Medina with the Holy Prophet (PBUH), so he sent several people to wait for Zainab near Mecca and accompany her to Medina. Upon learning of the departure of the daughter of the Holy Prophet (PBUH), a group decided to bring her back halfway, so when they attacked Kajaveh Zainab, Zainab was frightened and had an abortion and returned to Mecca. The Holy Prophet (PBUH) was very upset to hear this news and considered the blood of the murderer of Zainab's son permissible in the conquest of Mecca. Ibn Abi Al-Hadid says: I called this process to my teacher Abu Ja'far Naqib. (SA) was frightened that caused his son to have an abortion "Mohsen", he must have considered it permissible.

Abu Ja'far says with conviction that if the Holy Prophet (PBUH) witnessed the sufferings that were inflicted on his dear daughter, he would consider the blood of the perpetrators permissible. It was mentioned. Safavid narrates another Sunni scholar that on the day of allegiance, Fatemeh Zahra (PBUH) was really beaten to death that Mohsen had an abortion and after that Fatemeh Zahra (PBUH) passed away. -Skuni, who is one of the narrators of Sunni and reliable hadith, quotes in the news that I had a daughter and I was upset about this case. I went to Imam Sadegh (AS), told him the story and he asked what did you name your daughter? I said: Fatima, she said: Oh, oh, then she put her hand on her forehead and seemed to be crying. Is Sukuni says that Imam Sadegh (AS) was always like this, when the name of Fatima was mentioned in front of Hazrat, he remembered his grandfather and remembered her calamities and always reminded him and said: the cause of death and martyrdom Fatemeh Zahra (PBUH) was a blow inflicted on her by Qanfiz, a slave. Although Sakuni quotes the words of the Imam so far and does not mention the rest of the words of the Imam due to Sunni prejudice, but Abu Basir states that the cause of death of Fatemeh Zahra (PBUH) was the blows that Gholam Omar's hemp with a sheath of sword on that Imam. Omar ordered, so he lost his son Mohsen and became very ill and did not allow any of his abusers to come to see him.
Therefore, considering that the Sunni scholars, although in the first centuries, referred to the events after the death of the Holy Prophet (PBUH) and the story of the martyrdom of Hazrat Fatemeh Zahra (PBUH), but later, in order to preserve the position of the caliphs, they refused to mention them. The existence of reports in Sunni sources can be well known in the story of the martyrdom of Hazrat Fatemeh Zahra (PBUH) and the perpetrators.